# Unable to extract data from list

Tags: list, dart, dictionary

I need to create a two-parameter asynchronous function that receives a collection of data containing names as its first parameter and a string as its second parameter. The function must search the data collection and return a list that contains the names that contain the string given as a parameter.

For example the collection could be:

```
var database = MemoryDatabaseAdapter().database();
var collection = database.collection('names');
await collection.insert(data: {'name' : 'Jonathan'});
await collection.insert(data: {'name' : 'John'});
await collection.insert(data: {'name' : 'Steve'});

var list = await fetchedNames(collection, 'Jo');
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    print(list[i]);
}
```

The print out should be:

Jonathan

John

but all I manage to do is get:

{name: Jonathan}

{name: John}

What I have done:

```
import 'package:database/database.dart';
import 'package:database/filter.dart';

main() async {

var database = MemoryDatabaseAdapter().database();
var collection = database.collection('names');
await collection.insert(data: {'name' : 'Jonathan'});
await collection.insert(data: {'name' : 'John'});
await collection.insert(data: {'name' : 'Steve'});

var list = await fetchedNames(collection, 'Jo');
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    print(list[i]);

}
}

    fetchedNames(collection, name) async {

     var kysely = Query(
    filter: MapFilter({
      'name': KeywordFilter(name)
    })
     );

     var results= await collection.search(query: questionnare);
     var documents = results.snapshots;
     var list = [];
 
     for (var i = 0; i < documents.length; i++) {
     list.add(documents[i].data);
       } 
      return list;
}
```

I am unable to get a print out of just the filtered names, but I get the whole rows printed, ie.
The print out should be:
Jonathan
John
but all I manage to do is get
{name: Jonathan}
{name: John}

Answer (score 0):

Inside the for loop, just add the name of the property to the variable `list`, for example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    print(list[i]['name']);

}
```